# Python and PostgreSQL running on Google Cloud Functions 2nd generation gives "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory /engine/base.py"

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I am using Google Cloud Functions 2nd generation in order deploy and run my applications.

**I deploy my application using the following command:**

```
gcloud functions deploy postgresql-python-examples 
--gen2 
--runtime=python311 
--region=europe-west1 
--source=. 
--entry-point=main 
--trigger-http
--timeout=540
--verbosity=info
```

Now when I run the code I get errors that a file `/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py` does not exists. For me it seems like this is some type of requirements issue?

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask
pg8000
SQLAlchemy
cloud-sql-python-connector
google-cloud-secret-manager
gunicorn
```

**main.py**

```
import os
import sqlalchemy


def main(request=None):
    """ Initializes a Unix socket connection pool for a Cloud SQL instance of Postgres. """
    # Note: Saving credentials in environment variables is convenient, but not
    # secure - consider a more secure solution such as
    # Cloud Secret Manager (https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) to help
    # keep secrets safe.
    db_user = os.environ["DB_USER"]  # e.g. 'my-database-user'
    db_pass = os.environ["DB_PASS"]  # e.g. 'my-database-password'
    db_name = os.environ["DB_NAME"]  # e.g. 'my-database'
    unix_socket_path = os.environ["INSTANCE_UNIX_SOCKET"]  # e.g. '/cloudsql/project:region:instance'

    pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        # Equivalent URL:
        # postgresql+pg8000://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>
        #                         ?unix_sock=<INSTANCE_UNIX_SOCKET>/.s.PGSQL.5432
        # Note: Some drivers require the `unix_sock` query parameter to use a different key.
        # For example, 'psycopg2' uses the path set to `host` in order to connect successfully.
        sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(
            drivername="postgresql+pg8000",
            username=db_user,
            password=db_pass,
            database=db_name,
            query={"unix_sock": "{}/.s.PGSQL.5432".format(unix_socket_path)},
        ),
        # [START_EXCLUDE]
        # Pool size is the maximum number of permanent connections to keep.
        pool_size=5,

        # Temporarily exceeds the set pool_size if no connections are available.
        max_overflow=2,

        # The total number of concurrent connections for your application will be
        # a total of pool_size and max_overflow.

        # 'pool_timeout' is the maximum number of seconds to wait when retrieving a
        # new connection from the pool. After the specified amount of time, an
        # exception will be thrown.
        pool_timeout=30,  # 30 seconds

        # 'pool_recycle' is the maximum number of seconds a connection can persist.
        # Connections that live longer than the specified amount of time will be
        # re-established
        pool_recycle=1800,  # 30 minutes
        # [END_EXCLUDE]
    )
    print("Pool OK with unix_socket")

    # Create a table
    with pool.connect() as conn:
        conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS votes "
            "( vote_id SERIAL NOT NULL, time_cast timestamp NOT NULL, "
            "candidate VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (vote_id) );"
        ))
        conn.commit()

    return "OK"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output**

```
Pool OK with unix_socket

[2023-04-12 10:53:43,301] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 231, in __init__ self._usock.connect(unix_sock) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__ self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3275, in raw_connection

sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pg8000.exceptions.InterfaceError) communication error
```

Comment: Have you tried running `gcloud component update` to make sure that gcloud components are updated? Also, it's best practice to provide the specific version for each package to make sure that you're using the latest version for each package.

Comment: `gcloud components update` did not help.